# Extracting data from a GET response/JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Haven't touched Javascript for a bit while and cannot find a proper way to extract data from a JSON object.
So I am basically sending a simple GET request to the Giphy API and attempting to get URL's from the response but for some reason I get all kinds of errors.
This is what I tried:

```js
    $(function() {
      $('#searchButton').click(function() {
        console.log("test");
        $("#result").append("test<br />");
        var xhr = $.get("http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=cats&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&limit=1");
        xhr.done(function(data) {
          console.log(this.fixed_height);
          $("#result").append("success got data<br />" + data + "<br />");
          console.log("success got data", data);
          $.each(data.results, function() {
            $.each(this.images, function() {
              console.log(this.fixed_height);
              $("#result").append(this.fixed_height + "<br />");
            });
          })
        });
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="searchButton">search!</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems. First, there is not a `results` member in the `data` object. The only thing I see that you can iterate on, in the data object is yet another `data` member. Second, inside the `images`, there is no `fixed_height`, just `height`. This works:

```
var xhr = $.get("http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=cats&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&limit=1");
xhr.done(function (data) {  
    $.each(data.data, function () {
        $.each(this.images, function () {
            console.log(this.height);
        });
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n9ffva83/

Remember `$(function () {});`is not needed in JSFiddle, so you must provided (just the way you do in the code you gave us above).

**EDIT**:
To just get the url of the fixed height try this:

```
var xhr = $.get("http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=cats&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&limit=1");
xhr.done(function (data) {  
    $.each(data.data, function () {
        console.log(this.images.fixed_height.url);
    })
});
```

It seems this url is only one, that belong to the images.

http://jsfiddle.net/n9ffva83/1/

Comment: Alright, so if I want to extract only url part of the fixed height. Shouldn't this work: $(function () {
    $('#searchButton').click(function () {
        console.log("test");
        var xhr = $.get("http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=cats&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&limit=5");
        xhr.done(function (data) {
            $.each(data.data, function () {
                $.each(this.images, function () {
                    $.each(this.fixed_height, function () {
                    console.log(this.url);
                    });
                });
            })
        });
    });
});

Comment: Sorry for the code mess, don't know how to format it :/

Comment: Can't format in comments. I actually just saw the member you are talking about. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Hope it works. You can use the Developer Tools is you want to inspect your objects more closely. You can do `console.log(myObject)` and then in the Developer Tools you will see the object like a tree, with all of its properties and functions.

Comment: Nice, but for some reason I can only use the first URL I am getting. So if in my request I change the limit to 5 and I get 5 in the reply, how can I select which of the objects in the response I can use?

Comment: You can access using an index (remember data.data is simply an array). So you could do `data.data[0].image.fixed_height.url` to give you the first one, etc.